# How to safely access and write to a complex container from multiple threads in parallel?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a case where there is an unordered_map of structs. The struct contains int(s), bool(s) and a vector. My program will fetch data for each item in the map either through a https call to a server or using websocket (seperate https calls are required for each item in map). When using websocket, data for all items in the map is returned together. The fetched data is processed and stored in respective vectors.

The websocket is running in a seperate thread and should run throughout the lifetime of the program.

My program has a delete function which can "empty" the entire map. There is also a addItem() function, which will add new struct to my map.

Whenever "updatesOn" member of struct is false, no data is pushed into the vector.

**My current implementation has 3 threads:**

- main thread will add new items to the map. Another function of main thread is to fetch data from vector in struct. Main thread has a function to empty the map and start again. It has another function which only empties the vector.
- second thread will run websocket client and fills up vector in struct as new data arrives. There is a while loop which checks for exit flag. Once exit flag is set in main thread, this thread terminates.
- third thread is the manager thread. It looks for new entries in map and does http download and then add this item to websocket for subsequent data updates. It also runs http downloads at regular interval, empties vector and refills it.

Right now I have two mutex.

- One for locking before data is written/read to/from the vector.
- Second mutex is when new data is added or removed from the map. Also to use when the map is emptied.

I sense this is wrong usage of mutex. As I may empty the map when one of the vector element of its struct is being read or written to. This brings me to use one mutex for all.

The problem is this is a realtime stock data program, i.e. new data pops in every second, sometimes even faster. I am afraid one mutex lock for all could slow down my entire app.

As described above, all 3 threads have write access to this map, with the main thread capable of emptying it complete.

Keeping in mind speed and thread safety, What would be a good way to implement this?

My data members:

```
unordered_map<string, tickerDiary> tDiaries;

struct tickerDiary {
            tickerDiary() : name(""), ohlcPeriodicity("minute"), ohlcStatus(false), updatesOn(true), ohlcDayBarIndex(0), rtStatus(false) {}
            string name; 
            string ohlcPeriodicity; 
            bool ohlcStatus; 
            bool rtStatus;
            bool updatesOn;
            int32 ohlcDayBarIndex;
            vector<Quotation> data;
};

struct Quotation {
            union AmiDate DateTime;
            float   Price;
            float   Open;
            float   High;
            float   Low;
            float   Volume;
            float   OpenInterest;
            float   AuxData1;
            float   AuxData2;
};
```

Note: I am using C++11.

Comment: I try to follow this guideline:  immutable objects can be shared across threads, most mutable objects should be owned by one thread and not shared.  Shared mutable objects need to be protected by a mutex.

Comment: This is too broad. Yes, a map is not thread-safe, so you don't have much flexibility. Any kind of multi-threaded access that involves modifying the map will require a big lock on everything. You might be able to squeeze more mileage by using `std::shared_mutex` to allow multiple readers to lock the map simultaneously, but that's about it.

Comment: Given your description that you have two distinct data structures that can each be accessed (read and write) from multiple threads, one mutex to protect each is appropriate.   *Design* to avoid situations in any thread of attempting to lock both mutexes simultaneously, as that can cause deadlock.  That will usually mean (for example) grabbing mutex for the map, doing operations on the map, saving needed data in local variables, release the mutex, then grab the mutex for the vector .....

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Correct me if I am wrong. So, having two mutex is of no use here, right? A single mutex for both map and vector should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your map itself is primarily written in the main thread, and the other threads are only used to operate on the data contained within entries in the map.

Given that, for the non-main threads there are two concerns:

1. The item that they work on should not randomly disappear
2. They should be the only one working on their item.

The first of these can most efficiently be solved by decoupling the storage from the map. So for each item, storage is allocated separately (either through the default allocator, or some pooling scheme if you add/remove items a lot), and the map only stores a shared ptr. Then each thread working on an item just needs to keep around a shared ptr to make sure that the storage will not disappear out from under them. Then acquiring the map's associated mutex/shared_mutex is only necessary for the duration of the fetch/store/remove of the pointers. This will then work okay so long as it is acceptable that some threads may waste some time doing actions on items already removed from the map. Using shared_ptrs will make sure you wont leak memory by using reference counters, and they will also do the locking/unlocking for these refcounts (or rather, try to use more efficient platform primitives for these). If you want to know more on shared_ptr, and smart pointers in general, [this](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) is a reasonable introduction to the c++ system of smart pointers.

That leaves the second problem, which is probably most easily resolved by keeping a mutex in the data struct (tickerDiary) itself, that threads acquire when starting to do operations that require predictable behavior from the struct, and can be released after they have done what they should do.

Separating the locking this way should reduce the amount of contention on the global lock for the map. However, you should probably benchmark your code to see whether that reduction is worth it given the extra costs of the allocations and refcounts for the individual items.

Comment: Thanks @davidv1992 ! Regarding solution for first concern, could you direct towards some learning resource that has some example code to better understand how shared_ptrs can help Or better yet, could you give some sample code outlining its usage in this case. Being a newbie in C++, that could help me a lot.

Comment: Added a reference to an introduction on smart pointers in c++, which should help somewhat. Providing actual sample code is beyond the amount of time I am currently able to invest in this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using `std::vector` is the right collection here. But if you insist on using it you should just have one mutex for each collection.

I would recommend `concurrent_vector` from [INTEL TBB](https://github.com/intel/tbb) or a synchronized data structure from [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/thread/sds.html).

A third solution could be implementing your own [concurrent vector](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/214927/implementation-of-thread-safe-vector)